# Can a continuous functions intersect each horizontal line an uncountable amount of times

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cardinals

I'm looking to find out whether or not there exists a continuous function $f \colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for $\textbf{any}$ $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the equation
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\alpha
\end{equation*}
has an uncountable number of solutions.

I am tempted to believe that such a function doesn't exist, but I can't prove it. Despite this, I was able to find functions satisfying weaker conditions. For example for the function $f \colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x\sin x$ and for any $\alpha$ the equation 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\alpha
\end{equation*}
has a countable number of solutions.

An idea to build the desired function would be to try to replicate the behaviour of $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ around $0$, especially at plus minus infinity, but I can't quite get my head around this.

Comment: Such a function does exist (as you should suspect from Theo's answer below). Namely, choose a continuous surjection $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^2$ and compose it with the projection to the $x$-axis. (See e.g. Munkres' *Topology*, exercise 2 to section 44).

Answer (score 7):

Consider $\pi_1 \circ f$, where $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is a space-filling curve and $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is projection onto the first coordinate, i.e. $\pi_1(x, y) = x$. It doesn't give you everything (since it only has the range $[0, 1]$), but it's a start.

Comment: What's a space filling-curve? Is there an explicit formula for it?

Comment: Why not just use a space-filling curve $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this works. It would be interesting to see what additional information the space-filling curve which we choose tells us about the set of solutions to the equation $f(x)=\alpha$ for an $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Anguepa See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve) for an example.